# Binary expression in return statement neo4jClient neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to get the following Cypher query written out in GraphClient:

```
START agency=node(12345)
MATCH agency
        -[:AGENCY_HAS_PEOPLE]-()
        -[:AGENCY_HAS_PERSON]-person
        ,person-[?:PERSON_IS_CARER]-carer
        ,person-[?:PERSON_IS_CLIENT]-client
WHERE (person.UniqueId! = 18989)   
RETURN person, carer is not null as IsCarer, client is not null as IsClient
```

The query works fine in the console and returns the results I expect:

```
person           IsCarer    IsClient
Node(1545421)    True       False
```

When I try to write that query using Neo4jClient, it throws the following exception.

```
Expression of type System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression is not supported.
```

It is mainly due to the expression in the return statement:

```
.Start(...)
.Match(...)
.Where(...)
.Return((person, client, carer) => new
{
    Person = person.As<Person>(),
    IsClient = client != null
    IsCarer = carer != null
});
```

Is anyone already working on a solution for this?
Is there a workaround for it?
Is there any other way to write this query to get the same result?
If I were to implement a solution for this, is there anything related to the internals of Neo4jClient (limitation, pitfalls) that I should know before I begin?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/blob/master/Neo4jClient/Cypher/CypherReturnExpressionBuilder.cs

1. Fork the project
2. Clone it locally
3. Write a failing test that demonstrates the problem, in https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/blob/master/Test/Cypher/CypherFluentQueryReturnTests.cs
4. Fix the issue
5. Commit and push your fix
6. Open a pull request

When I'm happy with the quality of the solution, I'll accept and merge the pull request. The fix will then be published to NuGet within a few minutes.

Comment: I'll try to send a fix through after the holidays

Comment: @RajeevJoseph please get the latest version of the client, you should find the fix is in there